# Part android bottom sheet hides under tool bar android when expanded

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

My Action bar hides part of fragment, see image below:

[Actionbar hides under toolbar when bottom sheet is expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7ZYy.png)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    android:background="@android:color/white">
        <include android:id="@+id/itemised_bottom_sheet" layout="@layout/payment_itemised_list_layout" android:visibility="gone"/>
        <include android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_layout" layout="@layout/business_buttom_sheet_layout" android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use android:layout_height="wrap_content" instead of "match_parent" and make sure the content that goes inside bottom sheet has height smaller than the activity's view

Comment: tried this but did not work for me. What did the trick was to dim the android toolbar to enable view of entire screen in full screen with no interruptions from the toolbar. Code sample below

Comment: `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            if (dim) {
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent));
            } else {
                getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, getThemedResId(R.attr.colorPrimaryDark)));
            }

//            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(dim ? ContextCompat.getColor(this, Color.TRANSPARENT) : ContextCompat.getColor(this, getThemedResId(R.attr.colorPrimaryDark)));
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for the sheet layout.

```
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```